# Change input of flex from stdin to file?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

So I've been using flex for awhile, and the entire time I have been feeding it input directly from the terminal. Now I want to feed it a file. An adhoc solution I came up with was to use dup to change the stdin to a file, but am wondering if there's a way built into flex to do the same thing?

Comment: `yyin` is described [here, in the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/User-Values.html). And if you need to take input from more than one source, see [this chapter](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you can set yyin to a c file

```c
yyin = fopen("file.txt" "r");
```